# wordpress slideshow help

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wanting to add a slideshow to a couple of pages on my wordpress site, the client is wanting to be able to manage the images in the slideshow them selves, what would the best of achieveing this be? Could this be achieved with a custom content type? How could I give them this option while they are creating the page?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the [NextGen Gallery Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) by Alex Rabe.

It is a very complete gallery that is integrated in Wordpress,and has a nice button that install it in the Wordpress Editor, to let the user insert the gallery or albums!

It has numeros plugin if you want more effect other the standard that he can provide. Furthermore it has role management , so you can decide which option to give to your user.

I suggest you other plugins that extend the gallery

1. [Smooth Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-smooth-gallery/)
2. [JJ Slider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jj-nextgen-jquery-slider/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a ready made plugin for that. Try searching the codex:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=slideshow&sort=

Reinventing wheels is a thankless task in Wordpress, unless you have some very specific requests for functionality.

(Edit since someone answered just before me - The NextGEN gallery is very good, but you might find it overkill for your purposes - I'd recommend a little personal research first to find one of the popular ones that looks like it does what you want in a way you can live with)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources at themeforest.net